# URL encoding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a url of the form "users/:token/storage.json"

For example

/users/DCpjIfaTjxHd73zN%2FqEM3KJzwg6DEeC56%2FuCCH34FoFLaubZJsm4TsAgnprGnBx2jN0X4uoV2YW1JFarQFSwXegKrkcwQOI8mooWUl5eE7PdFnPLh5%2FTOQ%3D%3D/storage.json

I url encode the token before passing it in the url. This works fine on the development environment but in production the url gets decoded before hitting the routes file and this results in a different path as the token has a "/" in it.

The application is built using rails 2.3.8. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: can you post the code using which the above url is created.

Comment: perhaps `CGI.escape token` before you create the URL.

Comment: @Salil - This is the code that is use to generate the url "users/#{CGI.escape(DCpjIfaTjxHd73zN/qEM3KJzwg6DEeC56/uCCH34FoFLaubZJsm4TsAgnprGnBx2jN0X4uoV2YW1JFarQFSwXegKrkcwQOI8mooWUl5eE7PdFnPLh5/TOQ==)}/storage.json

Double escaping the token solves the problem. Not sure if the is the best solution though